# Related Rates - Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> An airplane is flying at an altitude of 8 miles and passes over a radar station. When the airplane is 12 miles from the base of the station, the radar detects that its horizontal distance is changing at a rate of 320 mph. Find how fast the airplane is flying at this point in time.

The question asks to find the speed of the airplane. I know $\displaystyle speed = \frac{distance}{time}$. And, in this case, if I were to draw a right triangle with the radar station and airplane, I get the distance as $\sqrt{80}$ miles. How do I then find time? Do I even have to find time?

If it helps, the answer is 160 mph

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: Edited my question. I don't know how to use mathematical notation on the computer though

Comment: @TheEconomist take a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/72616

Comment: This is a really weird question. The airplane is not traveling up nor down. We are told that the airplane is traveling at a *horizontal* speed of 320 mph. So isn't the speed that the plane is traveling at 320 mph?

Comment: @user2943324 Thank you for the complement.

Comment: @Quincunx, that's why I'm stumped. Could someone help? It is a valid question. It's out of an Oxford Math book.

Comment: @Quincunx, the answer in the book is 160 mph.

Comment: I think that the altitude and distance from station information yield no useful information. Focusing on the horizontal speed, the relative speed the radar detects will be $2h$ mph (as the radar pulse covers twice the distance), where $h$ is the horizontal speed of the aircraft. So $2h=320$, leading to $h=160$ mph.

Answer (score -1):

This question is dumb

Answer is 238 mph

CALCULUS IS LIFE

this question is bad because no life because no calculus

dx/dt = 320
dy/dt = 0
solve for change in hypotenuse

x^2 + y^2 = C^2
differentiate with respect to time

Comment: Please be more clear in oyur answer, this seems  un related !!!